# How to right align \part

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have been trying to right align the `\part` in latex, but without any success

Please also take into account the TOC input and the text formatting (fonts, etc. from the whole document). Basically I don't wanna change anything else in the basic part declaration of latex, except right justifying it and use a ":" or "-" instead of the "." at the end of the Part number.

I would also like the page number to be hidden.

Thank you guys!

PS: Unfortunately I can't post a picture of what I have right now.

I have found this code while searching the web:

```
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
  \refstepcounter{part}%
  %  add to TOC, but without page number (since this page is not counted)
   \addtocontents{toc}{\protect
      \nonumcontentsline{\numberline{\partname\space\thepart}#1}}
\else
  %  add to TOC, but without page number
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\nonumcontentsline{#1}}
\fi
\markboth{}{}%
{\centering
 \interlinepenalty \@M
 \normalfont
 \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
   % part number - UPPERCASE, and make it slightly larger
   \large \bfseries \MakeUppercase{\partname\nobreakspace\thepart}
   \par
   \vskip 20\p@
 \fi
 % part title - make it slightly larger
 \large \bfseries #2\par}%
\@endpart}
```

But whatever I do, I can't right align it. Tried the `flushright` environment. My other idea was to put it in a makebox to be aligned.. But that's not possible :(

### UPDATE

Using the `minipage` environment, I was able to right align the `\part` :-D yuhuu

I have just put the `\part` inside the `minipage` environment and played a bit its attributes. It works fine. But the remaining problem is how to get the part number and the title on the same line:

> **Part I: Title of the first part**

Comment: Haven't you forgotten to add your code? To remove the page number try this command `\pagestyle{empty}`, or this command if you want to remove the number only on one page `\thispagestyle{empty}`

Answer (score 2):

Using `\raggedleft` is sufficient.

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    %  add to TOC, but without page number (since this page is not counted)
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect
      \nonumcontentsline{\numberline{\partname\space\thepart}#1}}%
  \else
    %  add to TOC, but without page number
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\nonumcontentsline{#1}}%
  \fi
  \markboth{}{}%
  {\raggedleft
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \normalfont\large\bfseries % <-- Adjust here
   \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
     \large\bfseries\partname\nobreakspace\thepart: %
   \fi
   #2\par}%
  \thispagestyle{empty}% <-- remove the page number
  \@endpart}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\part{Title of the first part}
\end{document}
```

If `\large\bfseries` is not what you want, change it to suit.

Comment: Thank egreg for the suggestion. However, how can i have the part name, number and title on the same line? thanks

Comment: @pro They *are* on the same line.